# Magento 2.1 : Pagination of product collection

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection, pagination

I am working on a custom script (not custom module) where I need to fetch product collection and display 5 products at a time. After displaying 5 products there is a link **Next** which displays next 5 records and so on.

How can i do this. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DONE,

```
//your code goes here...
$page_number =  $_GET['p'];

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(5)
        ->setCurPage($page_number)
        ->load();

foreach ($productCollection as $p){
    echo $p->getName().'<br>';
}

$page_number++;

echo "<a href='?p=$page_number'>Next</a>";
```

Comment: use of object manager is no more recommended.

Comment: I was doing a custom script, not a module. How else we can create objects? Can you please suggest @Oscprofessionals?

Answer (score 0):

protected $_productCollectionFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

public function getProductCollection()
{
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
->setPageSize(5)
->setCurPage($page_number)  // you need to get page number
->load();

```
    return $collection;
}
```